# Sum up portfolio based on values

Tags: php

I am using php 7 and I get portfolio data via json.

I want to sum up the portfolio and created the following google sheet:

[image]

The final result is shown in yellow. Basically, if a stock symbol is from `asset_type` `stock` and then sum up or deduct from the symbol value.

Find [here the spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1H-Cgo65TUCG88p2TGqNkuCoDl1_t3sP2RAfwsDpWK8M/edit?usp=sharing).

I tried the following:

```
<?php

$data = json_decode('[{"owner":"Self","transaction_date":"2020-03-10","asset_type":"stock","trx_type":"sale (partial)","amount_range":"$15,001 - $50,000","symbol":"VWO","name":"Vanguard FTSE Emerging Markets Index Fund ETF Shar"},
{"owner":"Self","transaction_date":"2020-03-10","asset_type":"stock","trx_type":"sale (partial)","amount_range":"$15,001 - $50,000","symbol":"GOOG","name":"Alphabet Inc."},
{"owner":"Self","transaction_date":"2020-03-10","asset_type":"stock","trx_type":"sale (full)","amount_range":"$15,001 - $50,000","symbol":"VWO","name":"Vanguard FTSE Emerging Markets Index Fund ETF Shar"},
{"owner":"Self","transaction_date":"2020-03-10","asset_type":"stock","trx_type":"sale (partial)","amount_range":"$1,001 - $15,000","symbol":"GOOG","name":"Alphabet Inc."},
{"owner":"Self","transaction_date":"2020-03-10","asset_type":"stock","trx_type":"sale (full)","amount_range":"$1,001 - $15,000","symbol":"VWO","name":"Vanguard FTSE Emerging Markets Index Fund ETF Shar"},
{"owner":"Self","transaction_date":"2020-03-10","asset_type":"stock","trx_type":"purchase","amount_range":"$1,001 - $15,000","symbol":"GOOG","name":"Alphabet Inc."},
{"owner":"Self","transaction_date":"2020-03-10","asset_type":"municipal security","trx_type":"purchase","amount_range":"$1,001 - $15,000","symbol":"GOOG","name":"Alphabet Inc."},
{"owner":"Self","transaction_date":"2020-03-10","asset_type":"stock","trx_type":"purchase","amount_range":"$100,000 - $150,000","symbol":"AAPL","name":"Apple Inc."}]');

$portfolio = 0;
$res = [];
foreach ($data as $d1) {
    if ($d1->asset_type === "stock" && !in_array_r($d1->symbol, $res)) { //check if value exists in array
        foreach ($data as $d2) {
            if ($d2->asset_type === "stock" && $d1->symbol === $d2->symbol) {
                $a = array_map('intval', explode(" - ", str_replace(",", "", str_replace("$", "", $d2->amount_range))));
                $avg = array_sum($a) / count($a);
                // string contains - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4366730/how-do-i-check-if-a-string-contains-a-specific-word
                if (strpos($d2->trx_type, "sale") !== false) {
                    $portfolio -= $avg;
                }
                if (strpos($d2->trx_type, "purchase") !== false) {
                    $portfolio += $avg;
                }
            }
        }
        if ($portfolio > 0) {
            array_push($res, [$d1, $portfolio]);
        }
    }
}

echo $res;

/**
 * Check an array if an item exists
 * @param $item
 * @param $array
 * @return false|int
 */
function in_array_r($item, $array)
{
    return preg_match('/"' . preg_quote($item, '/') . '"/i', json_encode($array));
}
```

I get an empty `$res` array after running this code.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

I appreciate your replies!

Comment: What have you tried to debug your code? Have you checked inside the conditions? No errors? `$res` is an array, you `echo` it you should get `Notice: Array to string conversion` - use `var_dump()` or `print_r()`

Comment: Try to use Xdebug, or at least print stuff with `var_dump`. I personally would look first at all manipulations/reads of `$portfolio`, ex. `var_dump('portfolio old: ' . $portfolio, $d2->trx_type, $avg, 'portfolio new: ' . $portfolio);` and then simply dump the portfolio before the if where you push stuff onto `$res`.

Comment: `if ($portfolio > 0) { array_push($res, [$d1, $portfolio]); }` - condition is never satisfied.

Comment: @jibsteroos I know that this condition is not satisfied. I do not understand why this isn`t the case?